# Trying to reload a div with dynamic content from main page when closing a fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to reload a div on a main page when I edit the dynamic content in a fancybox.
The main page is made of an included php files. I thought I would be able to reload it.

I used the .load() function on the 'onClosed' element in the fancy box:

$(".add_form").fancybox({
'type' : 'iframe',
'onClosed': function() {
$('.param_middle_down').load('admin_inc_param_call_fav.php');
    }
 });

I would just like to be able to put it this way:
$('.param_middle_down').load('admin_inc_param_call_fav.php?**id=$i**');
where $i would be a variable sent when opening the fancybox.
I don't know if there is anychance to call the fancybox with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

try this
$('.param_middle_down').load('admin_inc_param_call_fav.php?id=<php echo $i; >');  provided it must be a php file not js file